# linking a specific user to a specific url sing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
 if(form.userid.value == "username1" && form.pswrd.value == "password1" || form.userid.value == "username2" && form.pswrd.value == "password2" || form.userid.value == "username3" && form.pswrd.value == "password3")

 {
  window.open('http://www.youtube.com')
  }
 else
 {
   alert("hello rising field student, your password or username is wrong!")
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is a code I have written in javascript, it actually takes a user to www.youtube.com after a successful login. I want a situation where each user would be assigned a specific url so when they login, they would be taken to that url. Thanks to anyone who would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: What issue are you having setting a specific URL which should be navigated to?

Comment: i just dont know how to put it there that i want user-x for example  to go to x-website and also user-y to go to y-websites and so on

Comment: You can use the same `if` statements, `var url; if (form.userid.value == "username1" && form.pswrd.value == "password1") {url = "/path/to/server/" + x; window.open(url)}`

Comment: thank you very much  guest271314, thing is  i'm a complete novice when it comes to javascript. I would like you help me re-write the code redirecting username2 to say http://facebook.com and username3 to http://google.com, from there i can just follow along and add other users thanks.

Comment: You can use the `if` condition at previous comment within existing `if` condition at code at Question

Comment: alright bro, please kindly help re-write the whole codes out, thanks.

Comment: You can write the code. At a minimum you can try to write the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: are you there @guest271314

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` condition for each URL which should be passed to `window.open()` for the specific user, and use a variable set to boolean `true` or `false` if either of the `if` conditions which checks `form` elements values evaluates to `true`

```
<script language="javascript">
function check(form) {

  var username = form.userid.value;
  var password = form.pswrd.value;
  var validUser = false;

  if (username == "username1" && password == "password1") {
    validUser = true;
    window.open("/path/to/url/1")
  } 

  if (username == "username2" && password == "password2") {
    validUser = true;
    window.open("/path/to/url/2")
  } 

  if (username == "username3" && password == "password3") {
    validUser = true;
    window.open("/path/to/url/3")
  } 

  if (!validUser)
   alert("hello rising field student, your password or username is wrong!")
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you describe "not working"? Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Have you read links at previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064977/linking-a-specific-user-to-a-specific-url-sing-javascript/47065524?noredirect=1#comment81078978_47064977?

Comment: By "not working"  I meant i copied your code and tried using it, it wasn't taking me to any url, yes i create a plnkr.co to demonstrate

Comment: I have created a  document at plnkr.co  so you can see how things are laid out, thanks in advance.

Comment: that's the url to the project at, you can just view the source code when it opens  plunkr.co https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj9i9ky0r00052y5srno8ohae/

Comment: please can somebody help me out here?